# CSS Drop Down Menu with Hover Effect

Tags: html, css

I've got a css-based horizontal drop down menu that works perfectly well, but I'm having trouble adding an effect that adds a top border on the item that represents the page the user is currently on. Here's the HTML code for the dropdown:

```
<ul id="browse">
    <li>
        <a href="/comedy/">Comedy</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/caddyshack/">Caddyshack</a></li>
            <li><a href="/backtoschool/">Back to School</a></li>
        <ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/80s/">80s</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/diehard/">Die Hard</a></li>
            <li><a href="/overboard/">Overboard</a></li>
        <ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I want:

- Hovering over an item changes its background color, as well as the background of the dropdown (the nested ul element)
- On the active page for an item, that item should have a 2 pixel tall colored border at the top.

Just to be clear, the dropdown already works fine, and I can already identify the "active" menu item. I just can't seem to figure out how to combine changing the background color on hover and adding a border-top on the active menu item without messing up the style of the menu somehow (either leaving a 2px tall blank space on hover, or having the hover background property override the border-top property on the active item)

I should also add, CSS-only solutions please.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: So, what you're trying to achieve is to get the hovered item background color to change, and when you're on the page (ex: on the "diehard" page), its list item will already have a top border?

Comment: What is the problem with .active {border-top: 2px solid red;} for example? If you have spacing problems, use .active {outline-top: 2px solid red;} instead!

Comment: @Jawad because adding a border just on that item pushes it down below the other items that don't have a border. I need the menu to stay intact.

Comment: @Jawad also note that outline is the same on all sides. In contrast to borders, there is no 'outline-top' or 'outline-left' property. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html

Comment: @rolling stone: Hard to say without the actual code. Maybe you can make space in there in such a way that the border does not "push" other items. Or as suggested, you could use the outline property.

Comment: @rolling stone: Ah! yes, you are right. Any possibility of a fiddle!

Comment: @Jawad I actually tried to add a fiddle but didn't know how to make it work since it needs different ids depending on the page for the properties on the active element to work properly :/

Comment: @rolling stone: Just add the navigational markup and the CSS for the funcationality of the navigation. It will be just an example. we can manipilate the spacing (width, height, padding, margins) in such a way that on hover it does not push other items. Or if it is a live site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the background color, it's fairly simple, just use code similar to this:

```
#browse a:hover {
     background-color: fuchsia; /*Whatever your background color is*/
}
```

As for the border effect, that's a little harder to do semantically, but I feel that [this article on CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/265-id-your-body-for-greater-css-control-and-specificity/) would do the trick. Basically, it involves adding an `id` to your body, and then referencing that `id` in the CSS so that only the specific pages will be affected.

**EDIT:** If you're having issues with your top border affecting layout (I don't know what orientation the navigation has), try reducing the margin or padding you have on each item by the size of your border (2px, in this case) to maintain overall box height. If you don't have any margins/paddings, try negative margins.

Comment: thanks @nightfirecat. i already had the background color and using id to select the active item, the issue is with the edit you added. that's an interesting approach, will try reducing the padding-top and see how it goes.

Comment: nice, reducing the padding-top on the active element to offset the border-top worked like a charm! thanks! knew it had to be something simple like that...

Comment: Yup, no problem - often the trickiest things to figure out are the simple things.